# PHP - Foreach object

Tags: php, arrays, api, twitter, laravel-5

I'm trying to loop through this data object in my view. However, I'm getting the following error: `Trying to get property of non-object`. This is the first time I've really ran into a issue with rendering arrays/objects...maybe it's just the case of the Sundays...but I can't get this `foreach` to output.

### Edit

I add the key/value "search_type" to the returned array - I think this might be causing the problem:

```
$results = $twitter->get("users/search", ["q" => $term, "count" => $num, "include_entities" => 'false']);
$results['search_type'] = 'people';
```

returns:

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": 1108217089,
        "id_str": "1108217089",
        "name": "Marketing",
        "screen_name": "SocialMedia246",
        "location": "Canada",
        "description": "Marketing|PR|Brand Consultant.Lover of Music|Fashion & life.A dynamic young entrepreneur with an unconventional out of the box approach to marketing & business.",
    },
    "1": {
        ...
    },
    search_type: "people"
```

Foreach:

```
@foreach ($search_results as $result => $profile)
    <div class="large-3 columns">               
        {{ $profile->id }}
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Minimized vardump, for search_results:

```
array:21 [▼
  0 => {#433 ▶}
  1 => {#435 ▶}
  2 => {#449 ▶}
  3 => {#455 ▶}
  4 => {#461 ▶}
  5 => {#468 ▶}
  6 => {#472 ▶}
  7 => {#479 ▶}
  8 => {#492 ▶}
  9 => {#505 ▶}
  10 => {#513 ▶}
  11 => {#526 ▶}
  12 => {#531 ▶}
  13 => {#538 ▶}
  14 => {#542 ▶}
  15 => {#548 ▶}
  16 => {#555 ▶}
  17 => {#560 ▶}
  18 => {#564 ▶}
  19 => {#577 ▶}
  "search_type" => "people"
]
```

Comment: can you do a var_dump on $search_results and ensure its an object and not a raw json string?

Comment: Just did - it's an array

Comment: change `$profile->id` to `$profile['id']`

Comment: Did that, `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: This is why I'm pretty confused

Comment: I think I know what's causing the problem. usr not sure how to fix it. In my controller logic, I'm adding a key/value pair to the array generated. i.e. `$results['search_type'] = 'people';` This is causing the keys to become numbers (i.e. 0, 1, 2 ...). I've updated post to reflect this.

Comment: Can you post the code where you're reading the json before the loop? I have a feeling you're mixing arrays with objects

Comment: can you please show the var_dump of $search_results ?

Comment: @VladimirRamik and Vasil - done!

Comment: "search_type" => "people" is mixed with an array type of structure - I would recommend moving it up one level

Comment: That's essentially what I came up with...but instead, just stored the results in a `people` array.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're not reading in the file correctly.

Please try the following loop:

```
<?php
    $sInFile  = 'in3.json';
    $sOutFile = 'out3.json';

    $sRaw     = file_get_contents( $sInFile );
    $aData    = json_decode( $sRaw, 1 );

    // $aData = array();
    // $aTmp                  = array();
    // $aTmp[ 'id' ]          = '1108217089';
    // $aTmp[ 'id_str' ]      = '1108217089';
    // $aTmp[ 'name' ]        = 'Marketing';
    // $aTmp[ 'screen_name' ] = 'SocialMedia246';
    // $aTmp[ 'location' ]    = 'Canada';
    // $aTmp[ 'description' ] = 'Marketing';
    // $aData[] = ( object ) $aTmp;

    // $aTmp                  = array();
    // $aTmp[ 'id' ]          = '1108217089';
    // $aTmp[ 'id_str' ]      = '1108217089';
    // $aTmp[ 'name' ]        = 'Marketing';
    // $aTmp[ 'screen_name' ] = 'SocialMedia246';
    // $aTmp[ 'location' ]    = 'Canada';
    // $aTmp[ 'description' ] = 'Marketing';
    // $aData[] = ( object ) $aTmp;


    foreach ($aData as $result => $profile)
    {
        var_dump( $result );
        var_dump( $profile );
        var_dump( $profile->id );
    }
    var_dump( $aData );

    $sNewJson = json_encode( $aData );
    var_dump( $sNewJson );
    file_put_contents( $sOutFile, $sNewJson );

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to get `id` property from string `people`.

Comment: Yeah, I was just about to write...it doesn't make sense. I'm going to remove the search_type key from this array altogether - save myself the hassle. Work it in my logic elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so @potfur brought up a good point in his comment. Instead of adding the key `search_type`, I'm just going to save the results to a `people` array like so. Save me the trouble and headache. Thanks for your help though guys. It was a mistake I should have picked up on.

```
$results['people'] = $twitter->get("users/search", ["q" => $term, "count" => $num, "include_entities" => 'false']);
```

vardump is now (which makes a lot more sense):

```
array:1 [▼
  "people" => array:20 [▶]
]
```